# Marketing Cloud File Drop Automation not triggering

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I am fairly new to marketing cloud and attempting to start an automation via a file drop to our SFTP folder. I have double checked this several times and it is not triggering the automation to begin. I'm including screenshots of my configurations below.

File Drop Starting Source Configuration:
Filename Pattern, ends with: _MAImport.csv in the folder import\missing_exam_reports

[image: picture of Filedrop Configuration]

I am using Filezilla to access my SFTP folder. And dropping a csv file named "10132023_MAImport.csv" into the import\missing_exam_reports folder.

[image: picture of Filezilla file drop]

Please help. What are some possible things that I could be doing wrong? I have activated the automation and dropped the file in again and again and it does not run. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you drop the `.csv` from your matching pattern?